# How to get mimetype of a field binary in Odoo10?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I created a binary field called `datas` and uploaded a file. I need to get the `mimetype` of the data.

i tried this.

***.py**

```
  attachment_icon = fields.Char(string="Icon", compute="_get_icon")

    @api.one
    def _get_icon(self):
        file = None
        for rec in self:
            print('data',type(rec.datas)) //it print type<str>
            binary_data = rec.datas
            print('binary_data',binary_data)
            mimetype = guess_mimetype(binary_data.encode('base 64'))
            print('mimetypemimetype',mimetype)// print 'text/plain'
```

Now the output of `mimetype` is `text/plain`, actually the uploaded file was `pdf`.
How can i get correct mimetype?

Comment: You can try [libmagic.from_buffer](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/master/magic.py#L156) which accepts binary string and returns the detected filetype.

Answer (score -1):

**Hello @KbiR**

Python's magic function will get the mimetype:

```
import magic
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
mime.from_file("youtPath/fileName.pdf") # 'application/pdf'
```